# How to specify Hive database name in command line while importing data from RDBMS into Hive using Sqoop ?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

I need to import data from RDBMS table into remote Hive machine. How can i achieve this using Sqoop ?

In nut shell, How to specify hive database name and the hive machine i/p in the import command?

Please help me with appropriate sqoop command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the `sqoop` command on the machine where you have Hive installed, because `sqoop` will look for `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive` to execute the `CREATE TABLE ...` and other statements.

Alternatively, you could use `sqoop` with the `--hive-home` command line option to specify where your Hive is installed (just overrides `$HIVE_HOME`)

To connect to your remote RDBMS:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote-server/mytable --username xxx --password yyy
```

To import into Hive:

```
sqoop import --hive-import
```

You can get a more comprehensive list of commands by looking at http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal">this link.